# Getting windows printer status via exec()

Tags: php, windows, command-line, printing

Is there a way to return the status of a printer via the exec function in PHP?

I am assuming not.  I've tried running print.exe and printui.exe, but they always just return 0 because they are accessed via the rundll32.exe.

Is there a way to access printui.exe NOT via rundll.exe?

Comment: How many times would you post this question ?

Comment: I expect you could exec out to cscript.exe and run a script that uses WMI to get the data you need.  Or perhaps PHP allows you to make WMI queries directly?

Comment: Awesome... Thanks harry.  I am using WMI through the Com class in php.